# tausend as an adjective

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

I know that numbers don't get conjugated (if this is the right verb to use in this case) like adjectives in German. For example:

> Es gibt tausend Unternehmen in dieser Stadt.

But I have encountered this sentence:

> Bundesweit unterstützen **tausende** Unternehmen diese Stiftung.

Why is it here "tausende" not "tausend"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although they are not conjugated, number words like "tausend" oder "hundert" can still have a plural, like in English.

> Es gibt tausend Unternehmen in dieser Stadt.

There are a thousand (1 000) companies in this city. (The sentence is as strange as it sounds, because it means that there are exactly 1 000 companies in the city, which is probably only approximately true.)

> Bundesweit unterstützen tausende Unternehmen diese Stiftung.

Nationwide, thousands of companies support this foundation.

The plurals of "zehn", "Million", "Milliarde" etc. work differently, by the way.

Comment: Shouldn't *Tausende* be capitalized because it is a noun?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Only if it stands alone: "Heute haben sich wieder Tausende angesteckt." Not if it stands with a noun like "Unternehmen".

Answer (score 0):

Because thousand**s** of companies do that, not a thousand.

Comment: So why this isn't tausende: Es gibt tausend Unternehmen in dieser Stadt.

Comment: "Tausende" is plural, it normally means 2000 or more. "Tausend" is singular, it means 1000.

Comment: Ok thank you guys